# Forward Looking vs Backward Looking Returns for Forecasting

Tags: time-series, finance

I have a general question about the best way to setup returns for a forecasting problem.

Most of the time I see issue of studying returns carried out with the following formula:

$ r_{t, k} = \frac{r_{t}}{r_{t - k}} $

So, essentially if you were studying one day returns you would divide the price today by the price yesterday.

However, I've seen other people do things in the opposite order, where they take the future price at some time lag and then divide it by the current price.

The former situation measures how much the price today deviates from the price at some point in the past.  The latter measures how much some price in the future is different from the price today.

If you would like here's some simple python code to demonstrate what I'm discussing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create mock data
dates = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', periods = 20)
values = np.random.normal(size = 20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'value': values})

# backward looking return
df['value'] / df['value'].shift()

# forward looking return
df['value'].shift(-1) / df['value']
```

The forward return is more intuitive to me because presumably if you are trying to forecast asset prices it makes more sense to look at input data today and then relate that to what happened n days later.  It maps better to how you'd want to use it.  But most people seem to set things up the other way, and I'm wondering if there are concrete reasons why you would prefer one over the other or if it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: If you're trying to test the power of a return forecasting algorithm, then forward returns are what you want to use as your left-hand-side variable so to speak. You can *use* back returns as a predictor (right hand side variable) however, because they don't have lookahead bias.

Comment: Could any of you provide a reference (or more), where they have implemented forward returns in a forecasting scenario?

Comment: @Pleb We do it at a place that I work at.

Comment: @Pleb The idea behind it is that if you use a forward return as a target variable it maps more cleanly to how you'd want to use a model to make forecasts.  So for `X` you have various financial indicators that you observe today, and then for `y` you have the return for some amount of days in the future, and then you can use a model to predict what the returns will be next week, month, year, etc given observed data today.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel Ah okay, I misread your question. A thought: depending on how you would define your filtration, then constructing some simple predictive model using back returns $\frac{r_t}{r_{t-k}}=\alpha$ gives $r_t = r_{t-k}\cdot\alpha$ under the filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t-k}$ is the same model defined via forward returns under the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$: $\frac{r_{t+k}}{r_{t}}=\alpha$ gives $r_{t+k}= r_{t}\cdot\alpha$. These are both *k*-step forecasts of the same model evaluated at different times (time $t-k$ and $t$). Thus, both are estimated using the same *k*-steps ahead returns.

Comment: So, it *might* be a matter of taste.